# what do an undefined method [] mean in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, null

I get the following error:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

The related snippet in line 50:

```
 47: <%=h @contact.date_entered.to_date %></br>  
 48: Next event: 
 49: <% next_delayed_todo = @contact.next_delayed_todo %> 
 50: <% unless next_delayed_todo[:event].nil? %>
 52: <%= next_delayed_todo[:event].title %> </br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See how you have 3 consecutive lines of nothing but code in your view? That's a sign you should pull it out into a helper, in order to keep your views clean.

New view code:

```
<%=h @contact.date_entered.to_date %></br>  
Next event: <%= next_delayed_todo(@contact) %> </br>
```

Then in your helper:

```
def next_delayed_todo(contact)
  contact.next_delayed_todo[:event].title rescue ""
end
```

Note that the error you were getting is because of `next_delayed_todo` being nil. The first line of the helper method uses `rescue ""` to set an alternate value if it is nil. You can replace it with `rescue "none."` or any other string that makes sense.

Comment: although didn't answer the question, this is helpful change I need to make...thanks +1

Comment: It did have a *solution* to your question, but I have added a note that makes it explicit.

Answer (score 2):

It means that you called [] on a nil object.  In this case, next_delayed_todo was nil.

You want something more like:
unless next_delayed_todo.nil? || next_delayed_todo[:event].nil?

Comment: Hi, I do have the following code a few lines up:        <% unless next_delayed_todo.nil? || next_delayed_todo[:event].nil? %>   hmm...so not exactly sure what to do...

Comment: ah, interesting...it's in my local but not on heroku I guess...let me make some adjustments.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the NilClass doesn't implement the [] method. Which in turn means that, in your code, next_delayed_todo is nil.

the .nil? you have now checks if the value returned by next_delayed_todo[:event] is nil. You should also add a nil check for next_delayed_todo

Answer (score 0):

NoMethodError: is an class derived from exception, is an exception. In a strong dynamically typed language if you try to use a method on types for which that method doesn't exist you throw a bad type exception.

method_missing is a function
 -http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005925

> Invoked by Ruby when obj is sent a
>   message it cannot handle. symbol is
>   the symbol for the method called, and
>   args are any arguments that were
>   passed to it. By default, the
>   interpreter raises an error when this
>   method is called. However, it is
>   possible to override the method to
>   provide more dynamic behavior. The
>   example below creates a class Roman,
>   which responds to methods with names
>   consisting of roman numerals,
>   returning the corresponding integer
>   values.

I think(don't trust me on this) the default method_missing function does something like a NoMethodError with the message "undefined method `#{method_name}' for #{inspectVariableValue}:#{ClassName}".

Answer (score 0):

I see an error in your code, unless should start a block, otherwise, like it is written the line does nothing.
So this should work:

```
 <%=h @contact.date_entered.to_date %></br>  
 Next event: 
 <% next_delayed_todo = @contact.next_delayed_todo %> 
 <% unless next_delayed_todo[:event].nil? do %>
   <%= next_delayed_todo[:event].title %> </br>
 <% end %>
```