# simple parsing in ruby

Tags: html, ruby, string, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Method to parse HTML document in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554909/method-to-parse-html-document-in-ruby)

If in the variable results I have:

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/><link             rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://2.ai/styles/hello.css" media="screen"/><title>Welcome to Dotgeek.org * 1.ai</title></head><body>..... etc
```

How can I parse, if possible without using any gem, the title of that HTML page that I now have  in the results variable?

Comment: Note: If this is for "general use" (ie, can expect any HTML that is valid), you should really REALLY use an HTML parser, not regular expressions or any other tricks that don't involve recreating the DOM

Comment: Why not use a gem? Nokogiri makes short work of accurately parsing HTML and is the recommended way of doing this. Otherwise look at [ReXML](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/) which comes with Ruby.

Comment: Yeah.. `Nokogiri.HTML(content).at('title').text #=> "Welcome to Dotgeek.org * 1.ai"`

Comment: but if you can do it with match without having to depend on yet another gem (since I am checking only for the title) why should I use the gem ? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
html = '<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://2.ai/styles/hello.css" media="screen"/><title>Welcome to Dotgeek.org * 1.ai</title></head>'
html.match(/<title>(.*)<\/title>/)[1] #=> "Welcome to Dotgeek.org * 1.ai"
```

Comment: Mandatory link for parsing HTML with regexps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/908515

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. That linked post "explains" why parsing HTML with regexps should normally be avoided. So, I posted it (although I admit that in the case given a regexp might be appropriate). Earlz's comment above is smarter but points into the same direction.

Comment: Granted, I didn't say your proposal is wrong. But we don't know the concrete issue. Maybe it is mission-critical software with a public web interface. So devnull should be aware of the restrictions.

Comment: both works - the page I am parsing is a standard parking page so I am just checking if the title is the one of the default one or not..why wouldn't this be good enough or dangerous ? doh! in 1 line I can save 2 gems (why? because gems do break and I don't want to depend on 2 gems for a simple check!!)

Comment: as a side comment what would be an easy way to convert the html ? seems not to work for pages with non standard characters...

Comment: solved thanks to someone in IRC https://gist.github.com/3670098 or better said adapted it to continue parsing if there are problems

Comment: i actually meant https://gist.github.com/3670449

Comment: The "mandatory link" is just a meme. It's not practical and the real answer when I last checked was on the second page. The HTML is easily parseable with regexes once you learn about them, learn about recursive regexes, not just copypasting memes.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply split by the title tag like this:

```
title = result.split(/<title>/,2)[1].split(/<\/title>/,2)[0]
```

(edit: the second parameter to split works different than I am used to from python and doesn't count the number of splits but the number of elements in the result array, meaning `split(/pattern/, 1)` actually doesn't split anything...)

Comment: hello, this seems to work too but I have an issue in a site that seems to use another language for the title see   curl =  %x(curl http://zales.1.ai) 
simian = curl.match(/<title>(.*)<\/title>/)[1]
puts simian throws in `<main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: The call to `match` returns nil because it can't find the pattern, and trying to use `[]` on nil leads to this error (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835428/what-do-an-undefined-method-mean-in-rails). The page you linked to does not contain a `<title>` tag (in fact, this is its complete source: `<h1>Ahoj svete :)</h1>`) so you can't match it.